# Hide / show line programatically in report

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013, rdlc, reportviewer

I am using a vb.net and the reportviewer to generate a report.
I need to programmatically hide a line depending whether a checkbox is checked or not. (A simple if statement).

How do I call this?
How do I refer to the reportviewer's line element?
How do I tell it to hide/show?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Is the checkbox checked before loading the report? Or it is a embedded checkbox into the report once generated?

Comment: @equisde its checked before loading the report

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the checkbox is ticked/unticked before loading the report, the easiest way to achieve that is by using `ReportParameters`.

`ReportParameters` allow you to pass values into your rdlc report. Once the report is loaded, you can define a report behavior based on the parameter values.

Code before loading the report:

```
'Retrieve the checkbox value
Dim isChecked as Boolean = yourCheckBox.Checked
'Create a new parameter to send to the report
Dim Parameters As New List(Of ReportParameter)
Parameters.Add(New ReportParameter("CheckBoxValue", isChecked))
'Send parameter to the report
ReportViewer.LocalReport.SetParameters(Parameters)
```

And after you've added the code, you also need to define the parameter in the `.rdlc` file as well.  With the `.rdlc` file open in Visual Studio, go to the `Report` menu and select `Report Parameters`.

To be consistent with the code, you should add a parameter named `CheckBoxValue` and then click `OK` to close the window.

Finally in your `.rdlc` report designer, you should select your textbox or label  and use the expression editor (right-click the textbox/label you want to show/hide and select `Expression`)

Here you'll need to write an expression based on this logic:

```
IIf(Expression as Boolean, TruePart as Object, FalsePart as Object)
```

This could be the expression:

```
 IIf(Parameters!CheckBoxValue.Value = False, yourTextBox.Visible = False, yourTextBox.Visible = True)
```

Comment: thank you very much. this works. very descriptive and helpfull

Comment: You're wecome! Glad to help